# Next.js app with Typescript will not build with async home page that gets query string values

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm still quite new to React, Next.js, and Typescript, so I apologize ahead of time if my terms are not completely correct...

I am trying to learn by creating an app that keeps track of when songs are performed.

On the homepage `app/page.tsx` I want it to display any songs scheduled between dates provided in querystrings `startDate` and `endDate`; that part works fine in dev but when I come to build I'm getting an error that seems related to the querystrings I'm fetching, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. It may also be related in some way to the fact that I made it async?

Here's the code for the page:

```
import GetSongsByDate from '@/app/lib/getsongsbydate';
import React from 'react';
import SongList from './components/song/SongList';

interface DateRange {
    startDate: string;
    endDate?: string; // Making endDate optional
}

export async function Home({
  startDate,
  endDate
}: {
  startDate?: string | undefined;
  endDate?: string | undefined;
}) {

  const dateRange = { startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate ? endDate : startDate } as DateRange;
  const songs = await GetSongsByDate(dateRange);

  return (
    <>
      {songs &&
        <div className={"home-song-list"}>
          <div className={"home-song-list-criteria p-5"}>
            Showing songs for {dateRange.startDate} to {dateRange.endDate}
          </div>
          <SongList songs={songs} />
        </div>
      }
      {
        !songs &&
          <>No songs found.</>
      }
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
.next/types/app/page.ts:8:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("C:/VS/GRCCReact/ptp/src/app/page"), "metadata" | "default" | "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | "dynamic" | "dynamicParams" | "fetchCache" | "preferredRegion" | ... 4 more ... | "generateViewport", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'Home' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '({ startDate, endDate }: { startDate?: string | undefined; endDate?: string | undefined; }) => Promise<Element>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

   6 |
   7 | // Check that the entry is a valid entry
>  8 | checkFields<Diff<{
     |             ^
   9 |   default: Function
  10 |   config?: {}
  11 |   generateStaticParams?: Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, typescript is inferring return type as

```
Promise<Element>
```

but its type should be

```
Promise<JSX.Element>
```

your component's jsx is conditional and it can end up returning `<></>`. I tried this and it gives error

[image]

if I change the return type to `Promise<JSX.Element>`, error is gone:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How did you know that was suppose to be the type? Experience?

Comment: first, try to understand the error message. it returns `never`  which is `The never type is used when you are sure that something is never going to occur. For example, you write a function which will not return to its end point or always throws an exception.`

Comment: then I looked at the `jsx`. it might end up returning `<></>` react fragment type.  I suspected that it should be type `JSX.Element` then I tested out to prove it